# Sort a list of elements in Zepto

Tags: sorting, zepto

It doesn't appear Zepto has a `pushStack` method. So we can't re-use the common `.sort` function [for jQuery here](http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2009/02/jquery-sorting-elements/).

What's the best way to sort in Zepto? Is there an `$.fn.sort`?

Answer (score 0):

Since Zepto uses an array (as does jQuery) for elements, I figured out I can use `[].sort`, like this:

```
            var $list = $(this).find('ul');
            var $items = $list.find('li');

            $list.html([].sort.call($items, function(a, b) {
                return $(a).text().toLowerCase() > $(b).text().toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
            }));
```

That will sort the LI elements by their text, case insensitively.